# Django orm - how to sort related fields when making Manager function

Tags: django

These are models for a restaurant booking service. Users can book a resaturant with their phone number, and can write down additional requests on request field.

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Reservation(models.Model):
   restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete_models.CASCADE)
   phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   request = models.TextField() 
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So I want to make a RestaurantManager named 'has_request_for_latest_reservation()' that returns True if the most currently made reservation of given restaurant has value in request field, but I can't figure out where to begin.

```
Restaurant.objects.get(id=1).has_request_for_lastest_reservation()
```

I can do this on the side of Reservation like this, but how do I do the same thing on the side of Restaurant?

```
reservation = Reservation.objects.filter(restaurant__id=1).order_by('-created_at').first()
bool(reservation.request)
```

Comment: You have to use Foreign Keys. Check Django documentation for it.

Comment: What do you mean with "has value in request field"?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/relations/

You can probably do something like this (the key is the `reservation_set` manager that's automatically created when you put the foreign key on `Reservation`):

```py
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def has_request_for_lastest_reservation(self):
        latest_reservation = self.reservation_set.order_by('created_at').first()
        return bool(latest_reservation.request)
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to define that on the `Manager`, you can define such method on the `Restaurant` model:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def has_request_for_lastest_reservation(self):
        latest = self.reservation_set.only('request').latest('created_at')
        return latest.request
```

this will return the `reqest` for the latest reservation, and if it is empty or `None`, the *truthiness* will be `False`, otherwise `True`, so you can use this in an `if` like:

```
if my_restaurant.has_request_for_lastest_reservation():
    # …
    pass
```

But it looks odd. If a restaurant has two reservations, then only the last one is interesting?